# Are questions about games created using Scratch on-topic?

Tags: discussion, off-topic

There is [quite the library of appreciated games](https://scratch.mit.edu/explore/?date=this_month&order_by=love_count) made using MIT's [Scratch](https://scratch.mit.edu) program. The program uses stackable blocks and pieces instead of raw code.

I'm wondering whether discussion or asking for debugging help about development of  games using Scratch would be on-topic here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as they are within the scope of the site (see: https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) then yes, they would be allowed.

For questions that are dealing strictly with the programming - just remember to ask yourself.

> Would a professional game developer give me a better/different/more specific answer to this question than other programmers?

Comment: Hurdle one cleared. Based on past experience, I would have to post a question requiring the tag in order for it to be created. That correct?

Comment: @scriptHero Yep.